# Why is this map<int, auto> not allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to implement a heterogeneous map in C++. I know that this has been previously discussed before but I was wondering why the following is not allowed:

```
map<int, auto> myMap;
```

Is there anyway in which I could make insertion into a map simple without having to resort to (void*) pointers?

I was thinking about eventually being able to do something like this:

```
vector<int> v;
myMap.insert(make_pair<int, int>(1,12334));
myMap.insert(make_pair<int, vector<int>)(2, v));
```

Is this possible? or are my efforts futile?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`auto` does not mean "this can be any type". It is a special keyword that can only be used to declare variables, and its meaning is "the type of this variable is the same as the type of the expression used to initialize it". The type of an `auto` variable is as unchangeable as the type of any other declared variable; the only difference is that you don't have to spell out the name of the type. Since `auto` is not a type, but just syntactic sugar for simplifying declarations, it cannot be used as a template parameter.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that! I misunderstood it to be as some kind of a 'any' replacement.

Comment: @P.R. I wish there was such a thing in C++; the lack of an ultimate base class (like Java's and C#'s `Object`) can be annoying. If there is a limited set of classes that you want to use, you could perhaps create a wrapper class (or a hierarchy of such) in order to avoid `void *`; apart from that, I don't have any ideas.

Comment: @P.R.: (In order for the wrapper class to be a useful substitute for `void *`, it must provide some methods for working with the wrapped data, so there might not be any point in doing it, depending on the types you want to put into your map.)

Comment: @Aasmund Thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately I don't know the set of objects. I am trying to write a class that has one of these maps as a member and then I want to pass this class around to other classes allowing them to add "data" to the class (the one being passed around) by pushing it into this map. I implemented the (void*) approach but the huge number of issues that can arise is forcing me to move very carefully with this.

Comment: @P.R.: I see. What are you ultimately going to do with the objects added to the map?

Comment: @Aasmund The objects will be accessible to any other class that wants to operate on the class holding the map. For example if class Car holds the map, Class PaintFactory will add an Object Color to class Car, and then when Car reaches the Class ShippingFactory, ShippingFactory will check to see what Color Car is (Some cars might not even have or need the Color property and that's why I need to add members dynamically at runtime)

Comment: @P.R.: It seems that you control the source code of the classes in question, and that they are all related to car properties. Can you make `Color` and the other classes inherit a class called `CarProperty` or something along those lines? (If this is going to be a publicly available API, it should be OK to demand that people who want to create their own factories make their classes inherit from your `CarProperty`.)

Comment: @Aasmund The items are totally unrelated. Maybe the car example was a bad one but the actual properties can range from an 'int' to a 'vector<Class A>' to 'map<int, string>'.

Comment: @P.R.: But whoever takes items out of the map must somehow know _something_ about the items in order to be able to use them in some meaningful way (and to cast them away from `void *`); I assume that a good mechanism for getting the items back into useful form is what you are looking for. So how are you doing this right now?

Comment: @Aasmund I am assuming that the caller knows the type of the resource it's requesting. I am eventually going to try and store the type somehow in the map itself.

Comment: @P.R. What about creating some kind of wrapper class containing e.g. a `string` and a `void *`, where the `string` describes what the `void *` points to? Or maybe even a hierarchy of wrapper classes, where each class contains a correctly-typed method that casts the `void *` for you. The map would then contain pointers to such wrapper classes. Of course, you would still need to cast the wrapper classes, but then you could use `dynamic_cast` and at least have the safety of run-time type checking.

Comment: @Aasmund I am going to try and implement some of that in the next hour or so. Thank you a lot for your help ! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @P.R.: No problem. Did you have any luck with it?

Comment: @Aasmund I eventually decided to drop the map idea since it had a huge hit on performance. Back to the drawing board I guess :/

Comment: @P.R.: Strange - maps should be very efficient (unless the value type actually is e.g. `vector`, in which case each insertion would copy the entire vector being inserted). Good luck, anyways.

Answer (score 5):

Just thing of extracting information from that thing, what would its type be?

You want something like `variant` or `any` from the `boost` library. They are still strongly typed, but with heavy use of templates.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use boost for this. I was thinking about extracting the information as auto and then casting it to some other type.

Comment: Then you think `auto` is `void *`. You have your answer already.

Comment: @P.R.: why "can't" you use boost for this? `auto` is a compile-time thing, nothing rtti related.

Comment: That was my initial implementation but I wanted to experiment with other possibilities.

Comment: @rubenvb I have to keep the code Independent from external libraries :/ I know... I know... depressing...

Comment: @P.R. at it's heart boost::any is not all that complicated, and it does not require much other headers, so you can always write something like that yourself should you need it using boost::any as en example

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for an *heterogeneous* map, not an homogeneous one. There are quite a few hits on google when you use that term, for example [Revisiting Heterogeneous Containers](http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/29757/1954).

Answer (score 2):

It's not allowed because it's not meaningful.  You can't *use* a value from this hypothetical construct with storing some meta-information about what type is stored in each instance (and a big switch statement), which is what e.g. [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/variant.html) does.